# How to make red color input box of error when no content is entered in box but the cursor is still in box using angular js?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, forms, validation

I am trying to add validation in my form using angular js. I want the whole color of input box to be red color when there is an error. My issue is that in my form after getting error when I am removing the text and  my cursor is inside the box , the color of box is blue and the border is of red color, i want the total box color should be red of border as well.Currently when I am clicking outside the box then only it is showing fully red and I need that if no text is there in box but still cursor is inside the box then also it should be showing error with whole box red color. 
I am using below styling-

```
.registration-form .has-error .form-control, .registration-form .has-error .form-control:focus, .registration-form .has-error .form-control:hover, .registration-form .has-error .form-control:active{

        border-color: red;
   box-shadow: none !important;
   background-color: red !important;
}

.registration-form label{
    font-weight: normal;
}

.registration-form .form-group input[type="text"]:focus{

    background-color:#18b6d6 !important;

 }
```

Can anyone help me how can I achieve that?
I have created a plunker here-

https://plnkr.co/edit/fFYhRMioVOMCyXWSYvUJ?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.registration-form .form-group input[type="text"]:focus{

    background-color:#18b6d6; // !important;

 }
```

Just take off the !important and it works

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this is the blue glow for input fields accessibility? If so, it's been answered numerous times on StackOverflow.

```
input[type="text"], textarea {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow:none !important;
    background-color:#18b6d6;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Include bootstrap library and it will automatically set the input box to red when it has errors:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Simple demo:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <form novalidate name="form">
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : form.input.$touched && form.input.$invalid }">
      <label>Input</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="input" ng-model="input" required>
      <span ng-if="form.input.$touched" class="help-block">Plan No. is required.</span>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Also, you can use [**`ngMessages`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) to validate your inputs, which becomes your application more flexible, I would recommend you to check this [**tutorial**](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages) also.

I have a complete code using `ngMessages` [**here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/XrXyVvo0KAfxXIwSqbHJ?p=preview), take a look.

I hope it helps!!